# Placing a slideshow before the content and sidebar - WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I'm trying to add an image slider before the content of the page which spans the full width of the page (I'm using bootstrap, so a 12 column div will be used).

Here is the current code for the `index.php` file:

```
get_header(); ?>

    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <?php 
            echo do_shortcode("[metaslider id=2010]"); 
        ?>
    </div>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        // The Loop

    <?php else : ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'index' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

As you can see, I've tried to add in the image slider just below where the header is called, but it hasn't quite worked. The image slider is being created with a width the same as the posts, as if it is part of the content. So the sidebar is still taking up the entire right side of the page.

I would like the image slider to span the whole page, and THEN the posts and sidebar are shown.

Any idea how to do this? I tried placing various things inside different divs and what not but can't seem to get the right layout

Update: `header.php`

```
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="content" class="main-content-inner col-sm-12 col-md-8" itemprop="mainContentOfPage" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">
```

(The rest of the code isn't really necessary as it's just the navigation and banner etc)

The image slider is then placed within this div above `main-content-inner col-sm-12 col-md-8`. The `main-content` is where the posts are output to, so I would need the image slider to go before this div. I could move this code into the `index.php` code, but I'm not sure if that is necessarily good practice. It's the only way I can see being able to put the image slider before the content

Answer:

Updated my `header.php` to this:

```
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <?php if (is_front_page()) { 
                    echo do_shortcode("[metaslider id=2010]"); 
                }?>
            </div>
            <div id="content" class="main-content-inner col-sm-12 col-md-8" itemprop="mainContentOfPage" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">
```

Comment: Since you are using bootstrap anyways, why not use the carousel template as an example and customize to taste? See this page and check the code: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

Comment: @Duncubuntu I'm helping to develop the website for a friend, who has no tech knowledge or programming knowledge, which is why I chose WordPress. So where possible, I'm trying to keep things simple for them. An image slider plugin is a lot easier to manage and update than a Bootstrap carousel I think! :P

Comment: Have you tried using container-fluid instead of col-sm-12?

Comment: @Duncubuntu Yep! I'm pretty sure I've just placed the image slider in the wrong place, but after numerous attempts, I thought I'd see if anyone here has any idea where I should be putting it. I thought about putting it in the header, but I don't want it to be part of the `header.php` template as it would be there if I go to a static page too.

Comment: post your header code

Comment: "The image slider is being created with a width the same as the posts" leads me to believe that its wrapped in something, maybe a div opened in the header, and closed in the footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

Above:

```
<div class="main-content">
```

Is where you want to call your slideshow.

If you don't want it to show on every page, use some conditional tags to control which page it appears on. See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Comment: Thanks, I posted the updated `header.php`code for you or anyone to take a look at if they're interested. Now I just need to tweak the styling! Thanks for your help.